# Import properly pkcs12 in Qt using QSslCertificate

Tags: c++, qt, pkcs#12

I would like to import private key and certificate using QSslCertificate.

```
QFile keyFile(QDir::currentPath()+ "/privatekey.pfx");
keyFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QString password = "Password";
QSslKey key(keyFile.readAll(), QSsl::Rsa, QSsl::Der, QSsl::PrivateKey);
QFile certFile(QDir::currentPath()+ "/certificate.crt");
certFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QSslCertificate certificate;
QList<QSslCertificate> importedCerts = QSslCertificate::fromData(certFile.readAll());

bool imported = QSslCertificate::importPkcs12(&keyFile, &key, &certificate, &importedCerts);
QSslConfiguration config = QSslConfiguration();
config.setCaCertificates(importedCerts);
config.setLocalCertificate(certificate);
config.setPrivateKey(key);
config.setProtocol(QSsl::SecureProtocols);
config.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyPeer);
```

According to documentation I load private key in format pfx. In debug mode each time I get false result from QSslCertificate::importPkcs12. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the API completly wrong. The key and certificate pointer parameters to the method are *out* parameters, you you should not fill them with data beforehand.

Assuming you have a PKCS#12 file that contains the main certificate, to get the private key, the certificate and optionally the certificate chain for the main certificate, the correct usage would be:

```
QFile pfxFile(QDir::currentPath()+ "/privatekey.pfx");
bool isOpen = pfxFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
// you should verify the file is open here!

// all default contructed, as they are filled by the importPkcs12 method
QSslKey key;
QSslCertificate certificate;
QList<QSslCertificate> certChain;

// now import into those three
bool imported = QSslCertificate::importPkcs12(&pfxFile, &key, &certificate, &certChain, password);
// imported should be true now, continue creating the ssl config as you did before
```